Making opportunities visible based off of business account owner
We are currently updating our opportunity visibility we would like the visibility to follow the below parameters:
1.They own the oppo (edit access)
2.They own the account related to that oppo (view access)
3.They own the business account the oppo is in (view access)
#1 and #2 are both done. #3 I am struggling more with.
Is there a way to have the opportunity visible to the owner of the business account that opportunity is connected to?
We have all our opportunities linked to an account as well as a business account.
Thank you in advance for the help :)

Have you looked at Opportunity Teams?  You can use Flow to create and add to the team.
